# How to view as high resolution in xcode4

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

Interface builder has an option Layout->"View as High Resolution" where has this option gone in xcode4?

Comment: Ok so its gone public now any answers?

Comment: Add some bounty and it'll pop back up to the active topics.

Comment: Can you indicate why you would need a High Resolution view in IB?

Comment: Typically I use this when building custom table view cells to blow up to double the size to make it easier to see.

Comment: A pity it's not there, just like with User Scripts. I hope support of Xcode3 ends when all the feature are implemented in XCode4 and not any sooner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That option is no longer supported in IB 4.  It may come back in an update.

Source -> http://blog.oleganza.com/post/4072983461/xcode-4-good-parts-and-bad-parts